# Saving glm object in R

Tags: r, save, glm

I am trying to save a glm object in R, but when I reload the file, I get a character vector with the name of the object I am trying to save.

```
>model = glm(X1 ~ ., family = binomial(link = 'logit'), data = datamatrix) 
>save(model, file = 'savedmodel')
>
>savedmodel = load('savedmodel')
>savedmodel
[1] "model"
```

Comment: simply using `load('savedmodel')` is enough.